# Regex using Python to replace dot of floating numbers with "dot"

Tags: python-3.x

I want to replace "." occurring in floating point numbers in my string with "dot" and vice versa.

Example:

```
t=' I am coder. I work in Google. I earn 98748.85'
Expected output: ' I am coder. I work in Google. I earn 98748dot85'
Then convert again: ' I am coder. I work in Google. I earn 98748.85'
```

My code:

```
 import re
 re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+',r"dot", t)
 output: ' I am coder. I work in Google. I earn dot'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're replacing the entire match with "dot", not just the dot.

I know of two ways of solving this:

#### 1. Positive lookaround assertions:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)',r"dot", t)
```

In this solution, you're only matching the dot itself, but assert that there is a number before and behind it.

#### 2. Catching the numbers and replacing with the capture groups and dot:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)',r"\1dot\2", t)
```

Here you match the entire float, but remember the part before and after the dot in capture groups. You then change the replacement string to be "the first capture group, then the string 'dot', then the second capture group".

Comment: Thanks. It's working for me. And you mean to say for .85 it will not work?

Comment: Yes, that won't work with these suggestions. Do you also want 34. to work?

Comment: If the first number is optional, then you may as well remove it, i.e. `r'\.(?=\d)'` or `r'\.(\d+)'`.

Comment: I meant: it should work for all cases like 85.85, 85.0, 0.85, .85 so on.. the code should be generic.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions? They would work for all your listed cases (but not for `34.`)