# Regex - Replace dots within bracket

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace dots within brackets with `re` with another string:

**from**

```
a = 'hello.mate(how.are.you)'
```

**to**

```
b = 'hello.mate(how|DOT|are|DOT|you)
```

I tried to use `/(` to highlight the beginning of the brackets and `/)` for the closing, but I am unclear how to capture the simple dot in between.

**The two most pertinent examples**

These two questions clearly faced the exact same problem, expecially question #2, but I can't seem to capture just a single dot in the `re.sub`

[Regex replace text between delimiters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515176/regex-replace-text-between-delimiters-in-python)

[Regex using Python to replace dot of floating numbers with "dot"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026240/regex-using-python-to-replace-dot-of-floating-numbers-with-dot)

**Attempted solutions**

Various ineffective attempts based on the examples above include:

```
b = re.sub(r'\(.\)','|DOT|', a)
b = re.sub(r'\(\.\)','|DOT|', a)
b = re.sub(r'\([.]\)','|DOT|', a)
b = re.sub(r'\([\.]\)','|DOT|', a)
```

Comment: Your problem is that you aren't allowing for anything to be between the "(" and the "."

Comment: A usual workaround would do here  - `re.sub(r'\.(?=[^()]*\))', '|DOT|', s)`. It won't work if the parentheses can be nested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can nest `re.sub` to first match string inside brackets and then substitute `.` for `|DOT|`:

```
import re

a = 'hello.mate(how.are.you)'

s = re.sub(r'\((.*?)\)', lambda g: re.sub(r'\.', '|DOT|', g[0]), a)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
hello.mate(how|DOT|are|DOT|you)
```

Comment: Brilliant - a complication for you, what if I want to remove all dots OUTSIDE of parentheses?

Comment: This is a different question @Pythonic which should be posted separately

Comment: @Pythonic Just from the head, probably exists better solution: `s = re.sub(r'(.*)(\(.*?\))(.*)', lambda g: g[1].replace('.', '|DOT|') + g[2] + g[3].replace('.', '|DOT|'), a)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely wouldnt a single re.sub with lookaheads be enough?

Comment: @yatu I'm not sure if that's possible. From my previous experience no, but I'm regex beginner.

Comment: not with lookaheads, but i guess with capturing group. Tel me figure it out for a minute

Comment: This solution will fail if the parentheses can be nested.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In this case is the regex right tool to use?

Comment: @AndrejKesely If you use PyPi regex module, it is. But you need the right pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed something like :

```
import re




a = 'hello.mate(.are.you)'




res = r'\([^\.\)]*(?:(?P<dot>\.)[^\.\)]*)+\)'

p = re.compile(res)

for m in  re.finditer(p,  a):

    print(m.start('dot'), m.end('dot'))
```

but i do not understand why dot is only ones captured

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
a = 'hello.mate(how.are.you)'  
content_in_brackets = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', a)
for con in content_in_brackets:
    a = a.replace(con, con.replace('.', '|DOT|'))
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what output you are getting??

Comment: And [here your code fails](https://ideone.com/YSJYTP), it should not replace `.` NOT  inside parentheses

Comment: I thought this was what we had to do, replace dot inside parentheses

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got your point. Thanks. I have edited my answer, let me know your review.

Comment: It is working but I am not sure it is the best solution for the current problem.